# Trying to add to do list contents on separate lines

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple to do list so I can play around with JS. I just wanted some additional help. When I press the submit button I want the text to appear on separate lines.

When I first click submit it seems to work fine, however after a couple of attempts the text appears next to each other.

Here is my JS and my HTML

```js
let click_submit;
   const  row = document.getElementById("to-do-txt");


function submit(){

   click_submit = document.getElementById("todo_input").value;

   console.log(click_submit);

   // row.innerHTML=click_submit;
   // display this in a p tag

   //whenever we click submit we want a new row to display

    display();
   
}


function display(){

    
    if(row.innerHTML.length==0){
        row.innerHTML=click_submit;
        
    }
    else if(row.innerHTML.length !== 0){
        const list = document.createElement('p');
        list.setAttribute('id', 'list_display');

        const new_content = document.createTextNode(click_submit);
        list.appendChild(new_content);
        
        const currentDiv = document.getElementById("output");
        document.body.insertBefore(new_content, currentDiv);

        //need to create new div p tag everytime submit is clicked
    }

}




     // function clear(){

     //     console.log("in clear function");
     //     click_submit = " ";
     
     // }
```

```html
<body>
    
    <!-- Enter to do -->


    <div>
      <input type="text" id="todo_input" name="todo" />
    </div>

    <div class="button-container">
      <button id="click" onclick="submit()" type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div class="clear-container">
      <button id="clear" onclick="clear()" type="button">Clear</button>
    </div>
  
    <!-- To do output section  -->


      <div>
        <div class="output">
          <p id="to-do-txt"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- Bin icon at end of to do   -->

    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your 'insertBefore' is wrong, that's why it's added to the boxy and not the output div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The way of inserting the new element is wrong, use the following were we insert on `outputDiv`, as the `firstChild`, or `null` if there is no child yet:

   ```
   const outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
   outputDiv.insertBefore(list, outputDiv?.firstChild || null);
   ```
2. You can only have **unique ID's**, so don't add the id when generating that element
3. You didn't pass the value to the new function

---

Applying those fixes:

```js
let click_submit;
const  row = document.getElementById("to-do-txt");

function submit(){

    click_submit = document.getElementById("todo_input").value;

    const list = document.createElement('p');
    const new_content = document.createTextNode(click_submit);
    list.appendChild(new_content);
    
    const outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
    outputDiv.insertBefore(list, outputDiv?.firstChild || null);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="todo_input" name="todo" />
</div>

<div class="button-container">
  <button id="click" onclick="submit()" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>

<div class="clear-container">
  <button id="clear" onclick="clear()" type="button">Clear</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div id='output' class="output">
    <p id="to-do-txt"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```